# self-intersection of lagrangian submanifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, symplectic-geometry

Let's consider lagrangian submanifold $X$ in symplectic manifold $M$. Is it true that self-intersection index of $X$ is equal to the Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$? Can we construct (not canonical) isomorphism between tangent bundle $TX$ and normal bundle $NX$?

Comment: These are definitely homework questions, and they follow directly from basic symplectic geometry. Either read introductory texts on it, or show us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let us prove $TX \cong NX$. Let $J$ be an $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure on $(M, \omega)$, so that
$$g(v, w) = \omega(v, Jw)$$
defines a metric on $M$ and $\omega(Jv, Jw) = \omega(v, w)$. Now if $v \in TX$, we have that
$$g(v, Jv) = \omega(v, J^2 v) = - \omega(v, v) = 0,$$
so that $Jv \in NX$. Hence we have an isomorphism
$$J|_{TX}: TX \xrightarrow{~\cong~} NX.$$

Now from differential topology we know that
$$e(NX)[X] = X \cdot X.$$
Since $NX \cong TX$, it follows that $e(NX)[X] = e(TX)[X] = \chi(X)$ and hence
$$\chi(X) = X \cdot X.$$

Comment: I think there is something wrong with this argument, mainly that the sign depends on wether the isomorphism by $J:TX\rightarrow NX$ preserves or reverses the orientation. Indeed, the self intersection of Lagrangian spheres in symplectic 4 manifolds is -2 (as for example in Gompf&Stipschitz). One way to see that the orientation might change is if you orient $L$ by an $J$ orhtonormal base ${e_i}$. Then $\{e_i,Je_i\}$ is also a positive orthonormal base and one can check that $\{[Je_i]\}$ is a negatively orthonormal base , atleast when the dimension is $4$.

Comment: I don't get how $g(v,Jv) = 0$ implies that $Jv$ is orthogonal to the whole $TX$. You only showed that $Jv$ is orthogonal to $v$ right?